# CSS arbitrary count of elements with equal width in a horizontal row

Tags: css, progress

I want to create a progress tracker like this one: https://hmv.com/hmvweb/checkoutRegister.do
but I need it fluidly so the surrounding DIV can change its width. I could give each list element a percentage width, but furthermore there will be progress trackers with different count of list elements. The list elements should fill the complete width and they should have a equal width.

Not a easy challenge, right?

Does anyone have a idea how to create a solution? I tried the display: table properties, they are positioned side by side but not like a wanted it (wrong width of the elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just wrap the elements up in an `<ul>` which has no list-style, display:block and a width of 100%. Then have each progress item within a series of `<li>` which have a float:left, no list style and an equal **percentage** width? This would require that you have a css style for the `<li>` based on the number of items but if you are using a CMS or can write some JS then you could attach the correct `<li>` style accordingly.

Comment: I used this method because of the good support of older Browsers (IE7). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the display: table properties, they are positioned side by
>   side but not like a wanted it (wrong width of the elements).

If you're [happy with](http://caniuse.com/css-table) a `display: table`-based solution, other than the fact that the width of the elements aren't equal, then the simplest thing to do is fix that problem.

You can do that by applying [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/table-layout) to whatever has `display: table`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/JBfE7/

Comment: Nice solution! Didn't know the property table-layout, but I used the other method because of lack of support of display: table in IE7. Thanks anyway!